# Dailymotion callback url dynamic configuration

Tags: callback, dailymotion-api

I hope I am not duplicating a question.  I am banging my head against a wall for several days now.  I am adding the Dailymotion PHP SDK to our site, I am using the Dailymotion::GRANT_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION, I am able to authenticate using a static call back url in my API on Dailymotion.

I want to be able to use this from several different scripts on the site.  The first will be to call a link up page, so we can capture that a person has linked to Dailymotion.  The second will be to upload video's through our system to Dailymotion, to that users account, not mine.  I know I could do this with the authentication type of password, but I want to use the API and not have to have the visitor sign in or enter their credentials every time.

Back to the question, I see that the API can have a dynamic url, but I can not figure out how to make this work.  If I someone could send me an example of how to enter this in the API section I would appreciate it.  This does not work:

http://example.com/dailymotion/[dailymotion_checklogin.php]

nor does something like this:

http://example.com/callback/[dailymotion_upload.php][dailymotion_checklogin.php]

I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Mrpepik

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `[dynamic]` part with your dynamic part.
If your redirect URI on your API key is `http://example.com/dailymotion/[dynamic]`, then your real redirect URI could be `http://example.com/dailymotion/dailymotion_checklogin.php`

Comment: So if I under stand you properly, all I need to enter after my http://example.com/dailymotion/ is [dynamic]?  And this will allow any page that is in the dailymotion folder to be able to be used as a redirect uri?  Just wanting to be sure.  I will test here in a few minutes to see if it will work.

Thanks for the reply.